# Swfitui Object not update when NavigationLink

Tags: swiftui, state, swiftui-navigationlink

All
Something is wired when use swiftui.
object is not update in closure whick assign on second view when navigate back.
code like this:

```
NavigationLink(destination:
                            DiscountsView(selectFunc: { (discount: DessertDiscount) in
                                self.collection.discount = DiscountEntity(discount: discount)
                                self.testDesc = discount.name
                            })
            ) {
                Text("优惠方案:\(self.collection.discount.name)")
                        .font(ViewApperance.shared.font)
                        .foregroundColor(ViewApperance.shared.fontColor)
            }
        )
```

The data Of collection not update, but testDesc update work, is anyone know what happen in this case, and what is the priciple of Object update in Swift?

Comment: There might be several reasons. Would show minimal complete reproducible example of complete scenario to avoid guessing?

Comment: thanks for the answer. i figure out the reason,the data will be replace when navigate back. the onAppear method of first view will request the data repeat, as result of the data will be replace. but there is an another issue, is there a way to distinguish lifecycle of view ,just like viewdidload、viewwillappear etc. in appkit?